# unable to capture context in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express

I am trying to understand how closures work in node.js

I have an express middleware grabbing the content of a remote site (*json). the situation here is that I am unable to update the express request (I think its possible) with the remote content to further process it in other middleware.

any help is welcomed :)

regards

```
    const request = require('request');
    const app = require('express')();
    const base = { url: 'http://api.xxx', record: 'todo' };

    function getFile(opts, cb) { // parse url using request
      request({
        url: opts.url,
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'request',
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        }
      }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error || response.statusCode != 200) {
            cb(error);
        } else {
            var ret = {content: JSON.parse(body), request: opts}
            cb(null, ret);
        }
      });
    }

    function grabData(req, res, next) {
    console.log(new Date(), req.method, req.url);
      getFile(base, function(err, data){

        console.log(data.content); // WORKS OK!

        //? How to get data.content injected in the request
        // req.contents = data.content // not working

           next();
      });

    }

// function calls ---------------------

app.use(grabData);

//app.use(furtherProcess)  //? how to pass args here?

app.get('/',  function(req,res){
    res.send("> "+req.contents);
    res.end();
});

app.listen(3000, function(){ console.log('Listen on port 3000...' ); });
```

Comment: try using req.pipe , so maybe something like this: req.get(opt.url).pipe(res) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any call to `next()` in your middleware. You need to call `next()` after modifying the `req` object:

```
function grabData(req, res, next) {
  getFile(base, function(err, data){
    req.contents = data;
    next();
  })
}
```

Comment: Sorry for that, I am unable to paste the full content so I did by parts and I forgot it :) still doesnt work (I already correct it with the next)

Comment: move your `next()` call inside the `getFile` callback() since it's async.